# Web Services in a Vaadin application

Tags: web-services, vaadin

I have a Vaadin application to which I added Web Services and now only the Web Services seem to be running on the web application. I see the Vaadin activity on the server but it's UI never shows up, Just a message about only the web services being available.

"Only functionality via web services available at this time."

Source can be found here: https://javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/validation-manager

Update:
I tried comenting the web service and still got the same effect. Here are the requested web.xml file contents:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--Comment if not using H2 database-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.url</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:h2:file:~/VM/data/validation-manager;CREATE=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.user</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.password</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.h2.server.web.DbStarter</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!--End of H2 database exclusive settings-->
    <filter>
        <description>Make GB2312\GBK or others to UTF-8 for chineese character support</description>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.validation.manager.web.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI to display</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.validation.manager.ValidationManagerUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>com.validation.manager.AppWidgetSet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ValidationManagerService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ValidationManagerService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ValidationManagerService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Web Service annotations:

```
package net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.validation.manager.web.service;

import com.validation.manager.core.DataBaseManager;
import com.validation.manager.core.VMException;
import com.validation.manager.core.db.Project;
import com.validation.manager.core.db.VmUser;
import com.validation.manager.core.db.controller.ProjectJpaController;
import com.validation.manager.core.server.core.ProjectServer;
import com.validation.manager.core.tool.MD5;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.openide.util.Exceptions;

/**
 *
 * @author Javier A. Ortiz Bultron <javier.ortiz.78@gmail.com>
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "VMWebService")
public class VMWebService {

    private Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getVMUser")
    public VmUser getVMUser(@WebParam(name = "user") final String username,
            @WebParam(name = "pass") final String password) throws VMException {
        VmUser user = isValidUser(username, password);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new VMException("Invalid username and/or password!");
        }
        return user;
    }

    private VmUser isValidUser(String username, String password) {
        VmUser user = null;
        parameters.clear();
        parameters.put("username", username);
        List<Object> result
                = DataBaseManager.namedQuery("VmUser.findByUsername",
                        parameters);
        if (result != null) {
            for (Object obj : result) {
                if (obj instanceof VmUser) {
                    try {
                        VmUser vmuser = (VmUser) obj;
                        if (vmuser.getPassword().equals(MD5.encrypt(password))) {
                            user = vmuser;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getProject")
    public Project getProject(@WebParam(name = "project") final Project project,
            @WebParam(name = "user") final VmUser user) throws VMException {
        Project p = null;
        if (isValidUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
            p = new ProjectServer(project).getEntity();
        }
        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getRootProjects")
    public List<Project> getRootProjects(@WebParam(name = "user") final VmUser user)
            throws VMException {
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        if (isValidUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
            ProjectJpaController controller
                    = new ProjectJpaController(DataBaseManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
            for (Project p : controller.findProjectEntities()) {
                if (p.getParentProjectId() == null) {
                    projects.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
        return projects;
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "saveProject")
    public boolean saveProject(@WebParam(name = "newProject") final Project newProject,
            @WebParam(name = "user") final VmUser user) throws VMException {
        boolean result = false;
        if (isValidUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
            ProjectServer ps = new ProjectServer(newProject);
            ps.copy(newProject);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your servlet mappings in web.xml (or via annotations) are not correct. Please show them

Comment: Added required details. Didn't want to spam so much in the question. That's why I added repository links instead.

Comment: Where is the mapping for the vaadin stuff?

Comment: Updated the file contents, some changes were not yet pushed to the remote repository.

Comment: Can you try to access some of the static VAADIN/... resources from the webbrowser? Your config looks ok for me. Do you have some kind of webserver in front of the servlet container you use? (What engine do you use?)

Comment: I use Tomcat. How could I try to get those resources from the web browser?

Comment: http://localhost/VAADIN/themes/whyteveryourthemeis/styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>validation-manager</display-name>
    <!--Comment if not using H2 database-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.url</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:h2:file:~/VM/data/validation-manager;CREATE=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.user</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.password</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.h2.server.web.DbStarter</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!--End of H2 database exclusive settings-->
    <filter>
        <description>Make GB2312\GBK or others to UTF-8 for chineese character support</description>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.validation.manager.web.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI to display</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.validation.manager.web.ValidationManagerUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>net.sourceforge.javydreamercsw.validation.manager.web.AppWidgetSet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>VMWebService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>VMWebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VMWebService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have had similar problems try this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```